# Hiding of member function does not work

Tags: c#, inheritance

I guess I have I miss-conception. I try to override the behavior of a class in a sub-class by replacing a public function. In the program below I expect "B" to be written to the console, but the program prints "A". Where do I think wrong? And how can I achieve it. (In my real case I cannot change class A).

```
    class Program
    {
        class A { public void F() { Console.WriteLine("A"); } }
        class B : A { public new void F() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A x;
            x = new B();
            x.F();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to declare F as virtual if you want this to work

Comment: If you want to learn more about hiding, I recommend to read this : [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18733/Method-Hiding-in-C).

Comment: Since `x` is of type `A` (even though its initialized with `B`), the compiler searches the functions there first, and it will run the `A.F()` function. Hiding only "hides" the member if the function is run directly on that type. You can't really inject functionality into a base type by overriding it with a derived type and hiding functions, then passing it to operations on the base type, it just doesn't work like that.

Comment: Understand. Too bad it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 3):

The desired behaviour can be obtained by using a `virtual` method and overriding it at follows; note the `override` keyword.

```
class Program
{
    class A { public virtual void F() { Console.WriteLine("A"); } }
    class B : A { public override void F() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A x;
        x = new B();
        x.F();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you happen to have a Java background, note that this type of inheritance is the default behaviour in Java, but in C# it has to be explicitly declared.